# Are there standard example research papers for teaching methodology and experiments?

Tags: research-process, writing, methodology, experiment-design

Are there recommended or standard published papers (not books) that show great research methodology/ scientific methods?  I am trying to help out a friend who is in business and they are trying to study aspects of humans (in terms of their clients).  I gave him the book [*The Craft of Research*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0226065669), but it's long and I wonder if there is a paper that could do the same job.  Basically I want to show him a good example of coming up with a hypothesis, accounting for variables (such as stating that something was done in order to eliminate a problem), and analyzing the results.

Comment: If he is in business and he can't even finish The Craft of Research, I'd rather suggest him budget some consultant money to hire someone (maybe you?) to work with him through the process. Learning and immediately applying research hastily would likely waste time and resources. It's correct that some papers may introduce some 101s about research design and analysis, but papers tend to be concise and use citation extensively; he may still end up needing to reference other publications and articles.

Comment: I know you didn't ask for books, but my answer may be helpful to you (and others). My PhD methodology is Design Science.  An excellent academic scholarly book, is "Design Science Methodology", by Wieringa, Springer, 2014.  There are about 100 references, in the book.  So you can learn from the book, and then find the relevance published papers that you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Qulatrics has a nice concise (and free) guide to doing marketing research. Not a journal article, but I give it to my students in my research methods course because it's practical and comprehensive but not overwhelming. In fact, they have a lot of useful resources here: http://www.qualtrics.com/university/researchsuite/research-resources/other-resources/ebook-downloads/

Answer (score 0):

I personally find a lot of both elegance and accessibility in the descriptions of well-done infant and animal cognition studies.  A nice source for examples is the [Harvard Laboratory for Developmental Studies](https://software.rc.fas.harvard.edu/lds/), and a nice short accessible piece from their library is this one: ["Chicks, like children, spontaneously reorient by three-dimensional environmental geometry, not by image matching"](http://www.wjh.harvard.edu/~lds/pdfs/Lee%20et%20al_royal%20society%202012.pdf): it's only 3 pages long, presents the hypothesis, method, and results quite tersely, and the experimental apparatus can be built with common household objects.